# Why my GPU with Ryzen 2400G is found as Radeon Vega 8 Mobile?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, lspci

I have a (desktop) Ryzen 5 2400G in my motherboard (B350) socket, so the iGPU should be detected as a Radeon Vega 11.

But every graphic command I use consider it is a Vega 8 Mobile, which is not even possible as it is a desktop APU.

glxinfo and lspci commands returns "Vega 8 Mobile"

From GUI it is the same, if I look at "details" in "parameters", I get : "AMD® Ryzen 5 2400g with radeon vega graphics × 8"

Actually I don't care that much if the displayed name is wrong but I would really like to make sure I enjoy my 11 graphical units instead of 8!

I'm using the amdgpu drivers with latest MESA and kernel.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: The 8 is not the number of compute units in the card, as I understand. For instance, my Vega 56 card is reported as "Vega 10."